Is there an exif tag in Sony a7R IV for the angle data (primarily pitch)
https://exiftool.org/TagNames/Sony.html lists a PitchRollYaw tag, but I can't seem to find it in the output from my (.ARW static image) files. It kind of looks like that might only be in video files? I need to figure out what the pitch angle for a certain (.ARW) photo was.

As it says on the exiftool page you linked: "Sony rtmd Tags
These tags are extracted from the 'rtmd' timed metadata of MP4 videos".  It won't be a single tag. Instead, it will be a stream of data that can be seen when using the exiftool -ee (-extractEmbedded) option on an MP4 file.

@StarGeek thanks, I did miss that bit! But I didn't look too hard for it either because of the MP4 only thing. Just tested and sure enough it doesn't add anything to the output for an ARW file. No surprise. :-(

@StarGeek Please put your answers in the answers section, even if they're short

The PitchRollYaw seems to be related to the sensor image stabilization. (check this article for more information).
About pitch - it is defined as "pitch - nose up or tail up" (axis parallel to the horison). Here is wikipedia article about pitch, yaw, and roll

Yeah that makes sense I guess. The "level" sensors in the camera (lines in the viewfinder) only apply to pitch and roll which makes perfect sense, because yaw (a) is visible to the naked eye clearly and (b) has no obvious "zero" angle, and would require a compass to measure. So any field with yaw present is clearly not what I was looking for (I doubted this field was what I needed anyway). I guess I'm just wondering if the data I'm looking for is under some other name that I didn't think to search for. I scrolled through all 2000 fields slowly but didn't see anything that looked right. :-(

Also yaw is not a leveling angle either.

@The111, by my understanding level is related only to roll (at least this is the situation in my phone)

The a7R IV definitely displays both pitch (aka tilt) and roll axes on the screen. That says nothing though about whether or not this data is persisted to exif in some encoding. The inner orange horizontal lines are for tilt, interestingly they will not go further away from the center mark than they are in this image (which I approximate very roughly as 20deg below level). And again this doesn't imply anything about what data is collected, maybe the sensor actually reads a full ±90deg but the UI clips it here. All 4 orange lines show roll, with no limits.

@The111, thank you for clarification, but from what I read this is info not from level sensor, but from image stabilisation (via sensor). Not sure if pitch and roll have the same soruce

Figuring out what sensor or hardware is responsible for the tilt indicators on my viewfinder is not really important here. Something in the camera is able to sense this angle, I am just trying to figure out if it's logged to exif anywhere. Seems unlikely.
